# facebook login button onclick event

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I am add login button as shown below,but something go wrong.  First two times I get facebook login window,but then something fails.  When login window starts open it closed.When I step by step trace functions invoking I find thet onConnect() function is not invoking.Any ideas?

my View:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    if (document.getElementById('fb-root') != undefined) {
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.type = 'text/javascript';
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e); 
    }
});

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({ appId: '455724271129246', status: true, cookie: false, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
};

function onConnect() { 
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {

        if (response.session) {
            window.location = "../LogOn/FbLogin?token=" + response.session.access_token;
        } else {
            // if user cancel
        }
    });
};

    </script>

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
 <body>
     <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <fb:login-button perms="email,user_checkins"
        onlogin="onConnect();" autologoutlink="false">
    </fb:login-button>
</body>
```

my controller:

```
      public ActionResult FbLogin(string token)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string JsonResult = client.DownloadString(string.Concat("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=", token));
        JObject jsonUserInfo = JObject.Parse(JsonResult);
        UInt64 facebook_userID = jsonUserInfo.Value<UInt64>("id");
        string username = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("username");
        string email = jsonUserInfo.Value<string>("email");
        ViewData["email"] = email;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a subscribe event:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        //do whatever
        login();
        // or onConnect(); 

    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
        //do whatever
        logout();

    });
```

Comment: after adding first function button not displaying yet)

Comment: Then look into your browser’s error console for … well, errors.